Transposing table in Jaspersoft Studio
I want to transpose a table of the following shape:
Date         | Type1        | Type2        | Type3
$F{date} | $F{type1} | $F{type2} | $F{type3}
In order to have a horizontal table like this:
Date     | ...
Type1  | ...
Type2  | ...
Type3  | ...
The only method I found was to use crosstab, but I haven't been able to find a detailed step-by-step explanation anywhere and don't understand how it works.
When defining the crosstab, I selected "date" as columns and "type1", "type2", and "type3" as rows. Btw, they are all fields.
But for measures, I don't know what to select. I don't want to aggregate anything, I just need the values horizontally, that's it.
To experiment, I've tried selecting either of the values and setting "No Calculation Function", but it doesn't work at all.
The layout of the crosstab is also very confusing and doesn't look like the table I want at all. I tried dragging and dropping the cells to rearrange it to look like I want it to look like, but that gives compilation errors. I don't understand the logic behind this thing at all.
Then I thought the issue may be because I'm selecting a dynamic value as column header. So maybe there is a way to create a vector with static column headers and use "Date" as row in the crosstab definition.
Could someone please give me detailed instructions of how to do this simple task?

If you have a fixed amount x of possible columns that fit on a page you can do it with changing the print direction of your report to horizontal and give it x columns in the edit page format-Dialog in the main report properties
